# Find normal affine subgroup $N$ such that $G/N $ is an abelian variety ( $G=\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus 0 $)

Tags: algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

I'm reading Shafarevich Basic Algebraic Geometry. I read Chevalley Theorem. It asserts that every algebraic group $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ is affine and $G/N$ is an abelian variety. I want to check Chevalley Theorem in one or two simple examples but I don't know how to do it.

For example: Let $X=\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus 0 $ this is an algebraic group endowed with the multiplication as the group operation. I want to find the affine subgroup $N$ but I don't know how =(

Comment: If the algebraic group is already affine, then the pieces in the Chevalley theorem are the trivial ones: the normal affine subgroup scheme is the group itself, and the abelian variety is the trivial group scheme. Note also that Chevalley's theorem assumes the base field is perfect. To get interesting examples you need non-affine, non-proper group schemes. For example, the identity component of the special fiber of the Néron model of an elliptic curve over a discretely valued field with bad reduction can be non-affine (and necessarily non-proper by the assumption of bad reduction), so its

Comment: Chevalley decomposition will be non-trivial. Also I should have said "abelian variety," not "elliptic curve."

Answer (score 1):

The commenter has already answered your question fully. However this piece of information is about a recent proof of Chevalley's theorem  by M.Brion (with many more results). Please see the link below:

https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/chennai.pdf